# Return collection where attribute of model records is empty in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following section of one of my functions:

```
$shipmentsNotSent = DB::table('shipments')
        ->whereNull(['billedAt','agentBilling'])
        ->whereBetween('date', [$startDateNS, $nowNS])
        ->get();
```

This works well but I am currently in the process of streamlining the models/controllers and a variety of other files, and I need it also to return only records that return nothing in the custom attribute (see below) I set up for the Shipment model.

```
public function getbillingUploadStatusAttribute(){
    $billingUploadStatus = $this->billingUpdates()->where([
        ['actionCategoryID', 1],
        ['actionID', 2]
    ])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
    return $billingUploadStatus;
}
```

So how would I go about filtering those records already filtered in the above controller function also return nothing in the attribute return?

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss Matthew, as to why you persist on signing your posts, and adding chatty material. You've been informed of our preferred style here seven times by me at least. You can clearly read English, and you're plainly not stupid. I am inclined to attribute contempt or malice to your character, but I'd much rather you just engaged positively with the community, so I can think better of you. Do you need meta references for our guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you're looking for `->whereHas()`:

```
->whereHas("billingUpdates", function($subQuery){
    $subQuery->where("actionCategoryID", "=", 1)->where("actionID", "=", 2);
});
```

That `subQuery` would essentialy performa the same `->where()`s that you're using in the function, but when used in a `whereHas` context, will constrain the parent Model records to those that match.

Note: This can't be used with `DB::table("shipments")`, but would rather need to be used on the associated Model (`Shipment`, I'm assuming). The full query would look like:

```
$shipmentsNotSent = Shipment::whereHas("billingUpdates", function($subQuery){
    $subQuery->where("actionCategoryID", "=", 1)->where("actionID", "=", 2);
})->whereNull("billedAt")
->whereNull("agentBilling"])
->whereBetween('date', [$startDateNS, $nowNS])
->get();
```

Edit: If you're looking to query for the non-existence of this function, use `->whereDoesntHave()`:

```
$shipmentsNotSent = Shipment::whereDoesntHave("billingUpdates", function($subQuery){
    $subQuery->where("actionCategoryID", "=", 1)->where("actionID", "=", 2);
})->whereNull("billedAt")
->whereNull("agentBilling"])
->whereBetween('date', [$startDateNS, $nowNS])
->get();
```

Comment: Hi Tim - I had mentioned that I needed it to return those without the attribute, would all I have to do is change whereHas to whereDoesntHave?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. If you want to query for the existence of that subQuery, then use `->whereHas()`, otherwise, `->whereDoesntHave()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for this, which is the opposite to `whereHas` as @Tim Lewis mentioned. Lewis gives a fine explanation on how it works, so theres no need to copypasta his legit answer content

> https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_whereDoesntHave

The query would look like:

```
//Assuming Shipments is your Eloquent Model
Shipments::whereDoesntHave("billingUpdates", function($advancedWhereDoesntHave){
    $advancedWhereDoesntHave->where("actionCategoryID", "=", 1)->where("actionID", "=", 2);
})->whereNull(['billedAt','agentBilling'])
  ->whereBetween('date', [$startDateNS, $nowNS])
  ->get();
```

Comment: Which has been established in the comments on my answer.